# how to give space between two input box field?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

how to keep space between this two input fields in bootstrap? need horizontal line

```
<div class="container">
           <div class="col-md-12">


            <input class="col-xs-3" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="AWB ID" style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px">

            <input class="col-xs-4" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Traking Information..." style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px">


           </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `col-xs-offset-2` class to your second input. This class adds `margin-left` to the element, and keep the horizontal line you need.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <input class="col-xs-3" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="AWB ID" style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px">

        <input class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Traking Information..." style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sucess but more space between inputs fielda

Comment: If you want more space, just increase the number at the end of the class name: `col-xs-offset-3` or  `col-xs-offset-4`.

Comment: Check [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for more references.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `{margin-bottom:20px;}` tag for give space between two input box field.

```css
#inputdefault {
  margin-bottom: 20px; //you want space 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="col-xs-3" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="AWB ID" style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px">
  <br/>
    <input class="col-xs-4" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Traking Information..." style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lion are you need horizontal line.

Comment: @Lion you can use  {margin-bottom:5px;}

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `&nbsp;` but that would look messy. Using 'margin' is better option.

```html
 <input class="col-xs-3" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="AWB ID" style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px"> <br>
<input class="col-xs-4" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Traking Information..." style="background-color:#DCDCDC; height:40px; margin-top: 5%">
```

Comment: Is is working. Please run the code snippet below my answer. For increase or decrease space change '4%' to whatever you want to achieve. @Lion

Comment: I need horizontal line

Comment: same results here

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do it like this.

First of all don't do this

- You should use id unique.
- try to not use inline `css`

Here you are using bootstrap so you can use form-group and add input in that form-group div.

Check this. it may helps you.

```css
.col-md-12 .inputDefault
{
    background-color:#DCDCDC; 
    height:40px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.col-md-12 .form-group {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
.col-md-12 .form-group:nth-child(1n)
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.col-md-12 .form-group:nth-child(1n)::before
{
    content: "";
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.col-md-12 .form-group:nth-child(1)::before {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="col-xs-3 inputDefault" id="inputdefault" type="text" placeholder="AWB ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="col-xs-4 inputDefault" id="inputdefault1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Traking Information...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="col-xs-3 inputDefault" id="inputdefault2" type="text" placeholder="AWB ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="col-xs-4 inputDefault" id="inputdefault3" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Traking Information...">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```